# Boolean If Statement with a Pointer to a Class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

```
#define NULL 0
class Sample{
    public:
        Sample():m_nNumber(0){}
     Sample(int nNumber):m_nNumber(nNumber){}
     ~Sample(){}
     int GetNumber(){return m_nNumber;}
     void SetNumber(int nNumber){m_nNumber = nNumber;}
    private:
    int m_nNumber;
};

Sample* TestSample(Sample* mSample){
 int nNumber = mSample->GetNumber();
 if ( nNumber%2 == 0) return mSample;
 return NULL;
}


void TestNumber ( int nSample )
{
    Sample mTest(nSample);
    Sample* mTest2 = TestSample(&mTest);
    if ( mTest2 ) /* Is this statement valid? or an Undefined Behaviour? */
    {
        std::cout<<"Sample is Even"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Sample is Odd"<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    TestNumber( 10 );
    TestNumber( 5 );
}
```

Given the following snippet I have a few Questions.

1. Is it an undefined behavior to return a 0 (NULL) from a function that returns a class pointer?
2. When doing a Boolean if statement on a pointer to a User defined class (if it's even allowed or does not result in an undefined behavior), does it evaluate the address of the pointer, or (EDIT) the value of the pointer?

I am using VS2008 due to the code I'm working on is a Legacy Source and it doesn't have updated third party Libraries.

Comment: 2) `if(mTest2)` is valid. And Address of the pionter is used since you're not dereferencing the pointer `mTest2`. Why do you expect the pointer to be dereferenced automatically?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: `NULL` should be `nullptr` but why do you think it would be undefined?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I've seen a post that one shouldn't be doing it. So I thought it would or could result into an undefined behavior and should instead dereference it first.

Comment: in that post the return type was either `Sample`, ie not a pointer, or the caller was dereferencing it without checking for null

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No, it should not. I doubt a 2008 compiler understands a  C++11 keyword. In modern code, yes. In this specific case, no.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number looking back at it yes you are right, the return was not a Pointer.

Comment: Side note, 'the address of the pointer` is a confusing terminology, all variables have addresses irrespective of whether they are pointers or not, 'the value of the pointer' is a better way to say it.

Comment: @nvoigt you are Referring to nullptr right? with my VS2008 SP1, I see nullptr in a line in vcclr.h but I'm not using it since it's inside a #ifdef statement (__cplusplus_cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it an undefined behavior to return a 0 (NULL) from a function that returns a class pointer?

It is **not** undefined behavior. The literal `0` is a "null pointer constant", and it can be used to initialize a value of any pointer type.

---

> When doing a Boolean if statement on a pointer to a User defined class (if it's even allowed or does not result in an undefined behavior), does it evaluate the address of the pointer, or the contents of the address?

`if(mTest2)` is a **valid** test. As you're not dereferencing the pionter `mTest2`, this checks whether the pointer is null or not and not anything about the content.

---

If on the other hand, you were to dereference a null pointer, then that would lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Both is perfectly valid and though some might argue better ways exist to handle this, still used frequently.

- NULL is a valid value for a pointer.
- Checking if a pointer is NULL or not is valid (that is what an `if` statement is doing in C++, checking if the value given is not zero).

What is not "allowed" is dereferencing a NULL pointer. So any usage of it beyond checking whether it is NULL would result in some ugly behaviors.